# Use a different session engine in each app

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Django project which involves the use of a REST framework (using DRF) in one app, and a web-based interface in another app. The REST framework uses the default session engine, which I believe is through database storage, in order to track user metrics more accurately. However, in the web-based interface, I want to use the cookies engine to provide simple authentication services.

Is there any way I could use two different session engines in two different Django apps, under one project?